# Need help with syntax of Instr in Access 2000. Trying to find values 0.0 to 9.9 in a text string.

Tags: ms-access

I am an Access novice trying to use Instr to select numeric data from a text string.

```
 Instr ( [start], string_being_searched, string2, [compare] )
      [start] defaults to 1
      string_being_searched is [Source Key]
      string2 is a number, decimal and number between 0.0 and 9.9
      [compare] is optional and I do not think it applies here
```

My problem is with string2, which returns a 0 for every occurrence when I use

```
 Expr1: InStr([Source Key],'#.#') or, with double quotes 
 Expr1: InStr([Source Key],"#.#")
```

If I specify a value such as 1.4 or 3.2 or even a text value such as QJX (not even a number) it returns the value specified, but I need it to select two numbers with a decimal point between them.

Please can you help as I am really stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need VBA, depending on what is to happen and the structure of the string.

You can say:

```
If aString Like "*[0-9].[0-9]*"
```

And

```
Instr(aString,".")
```

But you cannot use a wildcard with InStr.

You might get away with `Val(aString)` if the text is after the number:

```
aString="12.3 lbs"
Val(aString) '' 12.3
```

Or

```
Mid(aString,Instr(aString,".")-1,3)
```

Otherwise, you will need to consider Split or looping through the string character by character in a function.